# Bar chart in pandas

Tags: pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyV0f.jpg)

For a dataset like the one shown above, I need to plot a bar chart that shows the no. of 'Yes' and the no. of 'No' for each country. (Just one chart for all countries.)

Anyone can help?

Comment: should show what you've tried.

Comment: i have added the answer and let me know if that works

Comment: @TamilSelvan It works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your `dataframe` look like this,

```
    A        B  C     D
0  A1    Egypt  10  Yes
1  A1  Morocco   5   No
2  A2  Algeria   4  Yes
3  A3    Egypt  45   No
4  A3    Egypt  17  Yes
5  A3  Tunisia   4  Yes
6  A3  Algeria  32   No
7  A4  Tunisia   7   No
8  A5    Egypt   6   No
9  A5  Morocco   1   No
```

### Solution No 1

Using the `pandas.plot.bar()` you can plot. The solution can be,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('temp.xlsx')
g = df.groupby(['B', 'D']).size()
g.plot.bar()
```

outputput:
[image]

### Solution No 2

Using the `pandas.crosstab` you can create the perfect `dataframe` and use the `pandas.plot.bar()`. The solution can be,

```
df1 = pd.crosstab(df.B, df.D)
df1.plot.bar()
```

output:
[image]

Comment: I am adding the answer using the `matplotlib` as well which can give more detail to the bar chart